# How to partially match a pattern in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a list `lst` of objects of type `value` where

```
type value = A of int | B of bool | C of string
```

In doing some matching on the the list, I tried to write

```
match lst with 
| A x :: val :: tl -> ...
```

and got an exception saying that in the variable `val` a pattern was expected.  I am assuming this is because in the head of the list I matched on a `value` variant, but for `val` I wanted to capture all possible next entries in the list.  I can think of some ways around them, like writing several cases for the several variants of `val`.  But since I want to do the same basic thing no matter what `val` is, that seems like a very inelegant solution.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: `val` is a reserved keyword. Just call it something else instead. Also, I doubt you got an exception since exceptions happen at run-time. This would be a compile-time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating an answer based on glennsl's comment, I assume this snippet entered into the top level is reproducing the syntax error you're hitting:

[image: image of the error at the top level]

since `val` is a reserved keyword, it is not legal to use it in pattern matches. The error is saying that the underlined token `val` is triggering a syntax error since it is expecting something that could be part of a [pattern](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html).

The following should compile without any problems (using some random values for example):

```ml
type value = A of int | B of bool | C of string

match [A 1; B true; C "foo"] with
| A x :: v :: tl -> Some (x, v)
| _ -> None
```

And this is simply due to the replacement of the keyword `val` with the variable `v` in the pattern.

Comment: And if you don't need / use the `v` you can use `_` instead to avoid the "unused variable" warning and to make it clear it's unused.